# FLTK Group minimum size

Tags: user-interface, cross-platform, fltk

With FLTK (version 1.4.0), is it possible to set minimum size for an `Fl_Group` widget? Either explicitly or automatically so that it wouldn't resize smaller than needed to display *all its children*? The `Fl_Window` class has method `size_range` which allows to set the smallest window size, however `Fl_Group` doesn't have such a method.

If this is not available, then maybe there are some other way to enforce a constraint on how small a non-window group widget can be?

It is possible to partly achieve this by using the `size_range` method of the top-most window, however if we use `Fl_Tile` than each tile would not be constrained in any way. Yes, an `Fl_Box` widget inside an `Fl_Tile` can limit minimal sizes of the *outer* tiles, but it's not exactly what I need here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the resize method of an Fl_Group widget. The resize method is triggered automatically when resizing even if not called explicitly.

```
#include <FL/Enumerations.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Double_Window.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Group.H>
#include <FL/Fl.H>

struct MyGroup : public Fl_Group {
    MyGroup(int x, int y, int w, int h, const char *label = 0): Fl_Group(x, y, w, h, label) {
        box(FL_ENGRAVED_FRAME);
    }
    virtual void resize(int x, int y, int w, int h) override {
        Fl_Group::resize(x, y, w, h);
        if (w < 300 || h < 200) {
            resize(x, y, 300, 200);
        }
        
    }
};

int main() {
    Fl_Double_Window w(400, 300);
    MyGroup g(20, 20, 360, 260);
    w.end();
    w.resizable(&w);
    w.show();
    return Fl::run();
}
```

You will notice that the window is resizable, and if you try to decrease its size the group widget will get smaller to a certain point only.

Comment: Thank you, together with `size_range` for the main window it achieves the desired behaviour.